# EF Linq. How to keep "Where in" sorting

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a list of IDs and I need to retrieve entities from a database in exact same order, that IDs in the list.

Such query will return wrong order:

```
List<Guid> listOfIds = targetIds;
var result = await dbContext
      .TargetEnities
      .Where(x => listOfIds.Contains(x.Id))
      .ToListAsync();
```

I see a way to make requests in a loop and union result, but it looks too expensive.

How to solve that?

Comment: You cannot do that on the database. You can however do it afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have your list in memory, then try this:

```
var sorted = result.OrderBy(x => listOfIds.IndexOf(x.Id)).ToList();
```

---

If there are a large number of ids then using a dictionary is a good option to speed up the process:

```
var ordering = listOfIds.Select((g, i) => (g, i)).ToDictionary(x => x.g, x => x.i);
var sorted = result.OrderBy(x => ordering[x.Id]).ToList();
```

Comment: How were you able to post this, 3 minutes *after* the question was closed?

Comment: @nvoigt - I didn't. The question was well and truly open when I posted.

Answer (score 2):

Databases do not guarantee any order. SELECT commands may return the records in any order if you do not specify a ORDER BY clause. Specifically, there is no guarantee that the records are returned in INSERT order.

A database table is not an Excel sheet. I.e., there is no natural line number, because database theory is based on set theory and sets are by definition unordered.

You must specify an explicit order

```cs
var result = await dbContext
      .TargetEnities
      .Where(x => listOfIds.Contains(x.Id))
      .OrderBy(x => x.MyColumn)
      .ThenBy(x => x.SomeOtherColumn)
      .ThenBy(...)
      .ToListAsync();
```

There are also `OrderByDescending` and `ThenByDescending` extension methods to sort in descending order. You must begin with a `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` and can then optionally add multiple `ThenBy` and `ThenByDescending` calls.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I have no field for sorting, Ids in the list can be in any order.

Comment: You can add an [indentity column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property) that is incremented automatically that you sort on.